# MSSQL - Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm getting this error message

> IntegrityError: (2627, b"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
> 'XXXXX_TypeOfData_input_un'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
> 'XXXXX.TypeOfData_input'. The duplicate key value is (Processing Data,
> Processing Data Name).DB-Lib error message 20018, severity
> 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

How to add unique constraint when insert?

My code

```
INSERT INTO XXXXX.TypeOfData_input (TypeName, DataName)
        VALUES (%(TypeName)s, %(DataName)s)
```

My usual code for postgresql

```
INSERT INTO XXXXX.TypeOfData_input (TypeName, DataName)
            VALUES (%(TypeName)s, %(DataName)s) ON CONFLICT (TypeName, DataName) DO UPDATE NOTHING
```

Comment: You can use `MERGE` T-SQL statement. `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in one shot.

Comment: You should sort out your SQL injection issue, it's **danegrous**. Use parameters instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a MERGE statement to insert only if the record doesn't already exist.

```
MERGE INTO XXXXX.TypeOfData_input AS target
USING (VALUES (%(TypeName)s, %(DataName)s)) AS source (TypeName, DataName)
ON target.TypeName = source.TypeName AND target.DataName = source.DataName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TypeName, DataName)
    VALUES (source.TypeName, source.DataName);
```

Comment: but the current scenario the record already exist

Comment: you can do an update in a merge statement, when matched then update...

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS ...`